# Tankless Water Heater

Tags: yom-tov

Does the installation of a several gallon holding tank attached to a "[Tankless Water Heater](https://www.energy.gov/energysaver/tankless-or-demand-type-water-heaters)" resolve the problem of using the Tankless water heater on Yom Tov? Since the call for hot water will first be provided from the holding tank.

Comment: What is a tankless water heater?

Comment: @DoubleAA It is an instant hot water line. As soon as the water flows, a heating coil (usually electric) produces fully hot water without any warm-up transition. There is no hot water heater tank (like with a traditional water heating system which has a storage tank that is maintained at hot temperature constantly). Think of it like those electric coffee mug water heating elements.

Comment: A gas powered tankless heater is permitted if there is no fan since the flame is always there. Your idea should work for an electric one as well, if it has more than one usual use so it is not a psik reisha